# React native How to pass data from function component to class component

Tags: react-native, function, class

I'm using react native **functional** component to pass data to a **class based** component and I'm stuck 'cause I can't retreive the data in the class based component as I would in a function based component by storing **route.params.data** in a new variable inside the destination component. The reason why i have to use that specific class based component is that i'm using MultiSelect react native future that is built upon class component concept.
I passed the data from the functional component like so:

```
navigation.navigate('Order', { screen: 'Order', initial: false, params: {data : user_id},
                                                                })
```

and I should be doing this in the destination component to grab the data passed:

```
const info = route.params.data
```

But doesn't get the data in the class based component, so far as class based component can't use the route. So Please how can I acheive this purpose ? I'm also using **Redux** which already dispaches all that data inside all function components, but can't get use of in this specific class component because of class components' uncapability to use **Redux hooks**.
All help is much appreciated.
**NB:** The limitation I'm facing is having to use React Native MultiSelect in class based component only which can neither get passed value from a functional parent component, nor retreive redux datas from the sore.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In `multiselect.js`

```js
import React from "react";
import { View, SafeAreaView } from "react-native";
import MultiSelect from "react-native-multiple-select";

export default MultiSelectExample = (
  props /* getting the props from parent */
) => {
  // Create a selectedItems state, initialize it as empty array
  const [selectedItems, setSelectedItems] = React.useState([]);
  // Create a reference from the multiSelect
  const multiSelect = React.useRef(null);

  const onSelectedItemsChange = (items) => {
    setSelectedItems(items);
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <View>
        <MultiSelect
          hideTags
          items={props.items}
          uniqueKey="id"
          ref={(component) => {
            // assign the reference of the multiselect
            multiSelect.current = component;
          }}
          onSelectedItemsChange={onSelectedItemsChange}
          selectedItems={selectedItems}
          selectText="Pick Items"
          searchInputPlaceholderText="Search Items..."
          onChangeInput={(text) => console.log(text)}
          tagRemoveIconColor="#CCC"
          tagBorderColor="#CCC"
          tagTextColor="#CCC"
          selectedItemTextColor="#CCC"
          selectedItemIconColor="#CCC"
          itemTextColor="#000"
          displayKey="name"
          searchInputStyle={{ color: "#CCC" }}
          submitButtonColor="#CCC"
          submitButtonText="Submit"
        />
        {/* the '?' to check if a field in the object exists,
        at the first render of the screen the multiSelect.current is undefined
        so you need to check the existance of its properties or else it will throw
        an  error saying that undefined does not have function called getSelectedItemsExt*/}
        <View>{multiSelect.current?.getSelectedItemsExt?.(selectedItems)}</View>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

In App.js

```js
import React from "react";
import MultipleSelect from "./multiselect";

const items = [
  {
    id: "92iijs7yta",
    name: "Ondo",
  },
  {
    id: "a0s0a8ssbsd",
    name: "Ogun",
  },
  {
    id: "16hbajsabsd",
    name: "Calabar",
  },
  {
    id: "nahs75a5sg",
    name: "Lagos",
  },
  {
    id: "667atsas",
    name: "Maiduguri",
  },
  {
    id: "hsyasajs",
    name: "Anambra",
  },
  {
    id: "djsjudksjd",
    name: "Benue",
  },
  {
    id: "sdhyaysdj",
    name: "Kaduna",
  },
  {
    id: "suudydjsjd",
    name: "Abuja",
  },
];

export default App = () => {
  return <MultipleSelect items={items} />;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it this.props.navigation.params.data and and I got as result "can't find property 'data' of undefined. I try to check the this.props.navigation.params properties. For that I console.log(this.props.navigation.params) and I receive as result 'undefined' and when I console.log(this.props.navigation) I receive [object object]. What I'am missing ?

Comment: @Prenam isn't the MultiSelect a component in your screen? so why are you using class base component?

Comment: Yeah @Hamza Jadid, here the documentation [MultiSelect]https://github.com/renrizzolo/react-native-sectioned-multi-select#:~:text=react-native-sectioned-multi-select.%20A%20multi%20%28or%20single%29%20select%20component%20with,the%20future%29.%20This%20is%20based%20on%20https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Ftoystars%2Freact-native-multiple-select%20.) . I tried to use it inside a function component but unsuccessfully because MultiSelect's props are built upon class concept, for instance this `selectedItems={this.state.selectedItems}` which I can't change. Do you a way to use it inside function component ?

Comment: And the problem is That I'm passing data from a function component using navigation hooks to the class component implementing the MultiSelct component. The solution is to either find a way to use the MultiSelct inside a functional component, or to find a way to pass parameters from function component screen to class component screen. If I have to use MultiSelct inside function component screen, how would be the `<View>
          {this.multiSelect.getSelectedItemsExt(selectedItems)}
        </View>` written in a function component because right now it triggers errors, which make sens.

Comment: In the previous comment I made a mistake, the actual url for the MultiSelect doc I used is (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-multiple-select)

Comment: I see. You can pass props from a parent functional component to a child class component, in functional component we don’t use `this` keyword, if you define a function, e.g fn, inside your functional component you just call it without `this`, `fn()` instead of `this.fn()`. 
I’ll share with you a minimal code to use MultiSelect inside a functional component.